# console.log from published google web app script not seen in browser console

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a sample script provided by Google from https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server.

I could update the e-mail address and get the mail as well in spreadsheet, when I hit "send" button in index.html.

But I can't see the log o/p from console.log in browser console. I tried adding my own log line and as well tried commenting existing log of entire object, for no change in console o/p.

Later realized ( I should have seen this) that the script indeed runs at google servers and form-submission-handler.js is sending form data to the URL.

Once again, how do I see the logs generated by Web app script that we attached to the form, which runs in the Google server?
The console only shows the log lines from form-submission-handler.js

Any tips on how to view the log could be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Scripts can use `Logger.log` instead of `console.log`. To see its output, open the script editor and press Ctrl-Enter or select "view log" from the menu.

However, this log is not preserved for long: only the output of the most recent run of the script can be viewed. To have a real, persistent log, you need another solution. I sometimes use a separate spreadsheet for this purpose: so, instead of `Logger.log('Something happened');` it is `myLogger('Something happened');`  where the function `myLogger` looks like this:

```
function myLogger(str) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id of your spreadsheet here');
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.appendRow([new Date(), str]);
}
```

This function appends a row containing the timestamp and the string to be logged.

Answer (score 0):

Go to view > Stackdriver logs 
[image]

Click on "Apps Script Dashboard." link.

[image: Apps Script Dashboard.]